# Getting users location silently

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-location, clregion

In the process of developing a travelling application, let's say the user have a flight from LAX to JFK at 6:00 PM, is it possible to get the users location silently before the departure time (i..e 5:00 PM) and the users location after arrival?

I'm trying to achieve this using `While in use` CoreLocation authorization. Is it possible for example to execute some code on the triggering of a local notification? Or maybe I should look for another way to achieve this, for exmaple `Region Monitoring`?

I'm just looking for hints on how to achieve such behavior.

Comment: This what 'Always' authorization has been made for.

Comment: For your use-case region monitoring would probably be the best option.

Comment: @ZeMoon: "Always" seems like an overkill. A lot of users might not permit the app to use location services this way.

Comment: Region monitoring can tell you if they are at a particular location; say a few miles around the airport if that is the region you define, but won't trigger at a certain time. The only way to find out where they are at a time is always location, probably using significant location change mode.  If you app provides use/value then the user shouldn't have a problem with always authorisation.

Comment: @Paulw11: We're just looking to verify that the user actually traveled from said airport to the other airport. Think region monitoring would suffice? To the other comments, yes `Always` is certainly an overkill here and we're trying to avoid it.

Comment: Yes, region monitoring could work for that